# mongoose: the positional operator is not updating the element of an array of references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a single element in an array of references using the following syntax:

```js
Company.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ec424a1ed1af85a50855964"), 
  departments: { 
    "$elemMatch": { 
      "id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ec424a1ed1af85a508558495") 
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    "departments.$.active": true
  }
});
```

Here is the schema definition:

```js
const companySchema = new Schema({
  departments: [{
    id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Department"},
    active: {type: Schema.Types.Boolean},
  }]
});
```

When I run this code it does not update the database as it still reflects the original value.  I am not understanding why this is not working.  From the resources I reviewed online, this seems to be the approach.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the document you're trying to update?

Comment: Try `Company.findOneAndUpdate(...).exec()` or `await Company.findOneAndUpdate(...)`

Comment: @Cuong Le Ngoc, That did it.  I forgot to add exec.  Looking at this code way too much.  Thanks.  Lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, It might help you

```
Company.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ec424a1ed1af85a50855964"), 
      },
      {
        $set:{
          "departments.$[el].active": true 
        }
      },
      {
        arrayFilters:[{
          "el.id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ec424a1ed1af85a508558495") 
        }]
      }
    )
```